# Recover a deleted volume in Windows

Tags: windows, data-recovery, undo, logical-drive

I accidentally deleted a volume in Windows Disk Management. Is there an easy way to undo that action? Or do I have to use a file recovery tool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can recreate the partition the same exact size, you can then get the backup boot sector from the end of the volume. See [kb article 245725](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/245725) from microsoft.

Answer (score 2):

You can't undo it in Windows.

You need to either restore your partition table from a backup you may have made, or use recovery tools like [FindNTFS](http://www.partitionsupport.com/utilities.htm) or similar.

Comment: Thanks. Findtfs is really complicated, I didn't dare try it out. 

I tried http://findandmount.com/ which is free, but this works only with 32 bit windows. Then I tried various other tools, but they were mostly crap. Then I tried "Active@ Partition Recovery" (http://www.partition-recovery.com/), which worked great and was really fast. Unfortunately it's not free, but there is a demo to see if it will work in your case.

Answer (score 0):

[TestDisk](http://www.cgsecurity.com/) has worked well for me in the past, when I stopped a partition resize in the middle of it (bad idea).